# CSS background color center

Tags: css

I would like to center the image automatically,I do not want to use left and top
I want to establish what the center,

```
    <style>
#loading{
        position:absolute;
        background-color: #6B718B;
        font:40px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#ffffff;
        padding:20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        opacity:0.5;

}
</style>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

thanks

Comment: You can not center a background color, you can center the DIV. But you need to use `position absolute`, `left`, `top` and `margin`

Comment: Your question is not answerable in its current form. What image? Center in what? '*I want to establish what the center*'? Please rephrase your question in understandable English, and add more details about what you need.

Comment: What are you even asking?  Its like you picked three random words associated with CSS for the title, and then asked about an image, then gave an example showing a div.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to figure out what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a background image, you can do it like this:

```
#loading {
   /* Whatever other code */
   background: url("/path/to/image.png")center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants to align the DIV at the center of the screen

Comment: Maybe you are right - he said at the top "I would like to center the image automatically", and said he didn't want to use absolute positioning, so I reckon this is the only simple method that probably covers what he's actually doing. Wish people would ask better questions on this site!

Comment: Yeah thought because there isn't a background image, pls be more specific @user...

Comment: I bet you it's a fomatting error in the question.  I see a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Aligning it at the center horizontal is possible but vertical not with CSS. For horizontal center align:

```
margin: 10px auto;
```

But you could try JavaScript for that:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.top = height/3;
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.bottom = height/3;
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.left = width/3;
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.right = width/3;
```

Comment: I solved thanks

#loading{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #6B718B;
  font:40px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity:0.5;
  
  
}
</style>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
<script>
function finish(){
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById('loading').style.top = (height/2)-80;
document.getElementById('loading').style.left = (width/2)-150;
document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
</script>


<body onLoad="finish()">
Hello World
</body>

Comment: okay. (but you should format this code as code here (`))